# Xquery get value from attribute

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I have some xml and need to extract values using sql

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>  
<fields>  

<field name="fld_AccomAttic">  
<value>0</value>  
</field>  
<field name="fld_AccomBathroom">  
<value>1</value>  
</field>
</fields>  

</xml>
```

I need to get 
column name 
fld_AccomAttic
Value 
1

The xml is held in a sql server 2005 db

I have used xquery before and it has worked.

How to extract these values?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT <xmlfield>.value('(/xml/fields/field/@name)[1]', 'varchar(60)')
FROM <table>
WHERE <xmlfield>.value('(/xml/fields/field/value/)[1], 'int') = 1
```

Replace   with your table and field names.

Comment: I was hoping to achive a row view of the XML I.e 
      fld_AccomAttic fld_AccomBathroom 
Value        0                0 
Is this possible P.s many thanks for your original response Sp

Comment: This is the best example of this I have seen on the web. Can anyone point me to a good reference or tutorial that explains this?

Answer (score 7):

Figured it matey

```
XMLData.value('(/xml/fields/field[@name = "fld_AccomAttic"]/value)[1]','varchar(50)')
```